# PHP - var with HEX value: error on operation

Tags: php, hex, printf

Actually I'm developing a code that receive some base64 payload, convert it to hex and do some operations like below:

```
function temp($x, $y)
{
    $y = $y & ~0x03;
    $r = (($x << 8) | $y);
    $sht_temp = ((-46.85) + ((175.72 / 65536) * $r));
    echo $temp;
}

$a = base64_decode('aKpjU3MHsssS0/4=');
$b = array();
foreach(str_split($a) as $c)
    $b[] = sprintf("0x%X", ord($c));
print_r($b);


echo "<br>Temp:<br>";
echo temp($b[0], $b[1]);
```

The problem is, after the sprintf I got the hex with prefix like `0x68` as expected, but when the var is passed to the function, the result is not expected like if I type `0x68` on the function call, it's like the var is not a true hex value when it's is passed to function call `temp (0x68,0xAA)`.

I've tried a lot of possibilites, but always the problem persists when the var is inserted on function call.

**EDIT 1**

Other functions that shows the same problem:

```
function umidade($a, $b)
{
    $x = $b & ~0x03;
    $y = (($a << 8) | $b);
    $umidade = ((-6.0) + ((125.0 / 65536) * $y));

    return $umidade;
}

function tmp($x, $y)
{

    $a = ($x >> 4);
    $b = (($x << 4) | ($y >>4));
    $r = (($a << 8) | $b);
    $tmp = ((($r * (3300 / 1023)) - 500) / 10);

    return $tmp;
}

function lum($x,$y){

    $a = ($x & 0x0F);
    $b = $y;
    $r = (float)(($a << 8) | $b);

    return $r;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code I have found some issue which interrupt to get your expected output.

**The issue what I found:**

- You are doing a `bitwise` operation on a string like `0xA` but you should not do it. If you do this, a PHP `notice` will be thrown as following message

  > Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered ....
- You didn't return any value from `temp` method, so `temp($b[0], $b[1])` didn't print anything.

**My suggestion what to do**

- Convert the string to decimal number before performing [**bitwise**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operation using [**hexdec($str)**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)
- Return calculated `$sht_temp` value from the method `temp()`. Before returning you might convert the calculated decimal number to hexa using `dechex($sht_temp)` and prepend `0x` to the number if you want.

**Working codes:**

```
function temp($x, $y)
{
    $x = hexdec($x);
    $y = hexdec($y);
    $y = $y & ~3;
    $r = ($x << 8) | $y;
    $sht_temp = ((-46.85) + ((175.72 / 65536) * $r));
    return "0x" . dechex($sht_temp);
}

echo '<pre>';
$a = base64_decode('aKpjU3MHsssS0/4=');
$b = array();
foreach(str_split($a) as $c)
    $b[] = sprintf("0x%X", ord($c));
print_r($b);

echo "<br>Temp:<br>";
echo temp($b[0], $b[1]);
```

**Working** [**demo.**](https://3v4l.org/Ug823)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it's worked on the temp function but I've tried in others 3 functions that I've added in the post, but for something it's not working even if I use the ````hexdec````, do you know why?

Comment: Convert dec to hex when you return. Example: `return '0x' . dechex($r);`